# Rift Herald and Baron

Tags: league-of-legends

So I know Baron appears at 20 minutes exactly, but what happens to the RH?

Let's say you were doing the Rift Herald and it is mid life when the 20 minutes mark kicks in. What happens?

1. does the Rift Herald just disappear? Leaving a full life baron.
2. does the Rift Herald just disappear? Leaving a half life baron. (proportional to the % of health)
3. does the Rift Herald just disappear? Leaving a baron with some life missing (if you reduced 2000 health of the RH, then the baron will have 2000 health less)

Also, if you kill the RH, does it have time to spawn again before Baron spawns?

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: Probably because you could have known this if you had read the patch notes.

Comment: As the answer shows not everything is covered in the patch notes.

Comment: Also, if you would say "You can read it in patch notes" or a guide, or google it, this website would have 0 questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the corresponding patch notes:

> Rift Herald despawns at 19:45 unless in combat; hard despawns at 19:55 no matter what

I'm assuming baron will appear normally after the Rift Herald disappears. Meaning that it will take him several seconds to slither into his pit with full health.

Comment: Rift herald despawns at 19:55 because that's when the animation of baron spawning in begins. Baron will still show up at 20:00 on the dot.

Comment: full-life btw...